# Please reopen a closed question that has now an answer

Tags: support, status-declined

The following question titled "[Which Android phones are equivalent in performance to the latest iPhones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39772/which-android-phones-are-equivalent-in-performance-to-the-latest-iphones)" (asked by me) was closed as not constructive. However, I was able to find an answer which I think is constructive and could be helpful to others. 
I would suggest opening the question so that it and the answer will not be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

I respect that you want help others with re-opening your question. However our FAQ states that "shopping recommendations" are off-topic on Android Enthusiasts.

In fact all type of recommendations do not fit your Q/A format. A better approach would be something like the already existing question ["Where can I find a comparison of Android devices?"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/770/where-can-i-find-a-comparison-of-android-devices). The answers of this question also provide an answer to your question and the question is within the rules of our FAQ.

<sup>I personally can only recommend [geekaphone](http://geekaphone.com/): It allows the comparison of different smartphones including the Apple ones.</sup>

Comment: Geeekaphone is indeed an interesting site. I was not aware of it.

Comment: Although the question can assist in making shopping recommendations, its object is a relatively unbiased comparison between different platforms